# Find difference between first and second highest value in table having the same value in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named candidates that stores a candidate data in a US presidential election.

The columns of the table are:

- name(varchar)
- election_year(int)
- votes(int)
- winner(boolean)

I needed to get the difference between the most and second most voted candidates in all election years. I tried the stuff in google for second highest salary, but that assumes want the second highest in the whole table, and I only want the second highest from that election year, but I have no clue how to do it.

Can I get any insights on how this might be done?

The closest I got was

```
select max(votes) - min(votes)
from candidates
group by election_year;
```

but then it isn't exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a way to do it without using window functions and it goes as follows:

```
select max(votes - second_place_votes)
from election inner join (
    select election_year, max(votes) as second_place_votes
    from election
    where winner_loser_indic='L'
    group by election_year
    order by election_year
) as second_max_votes on election.election_year=second_max_votes.election_year
where winner_loser_indic='W';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the window function `rank()` in a derived table:

```
select election_year, max(votes)- min(votes) as difference
from (
    select election_year, votes, rank() over w
    from candidates
    window w as (partition by election_year order by votes desc)
    ) s
where rank < 3
group by election_year
```

Read in the documentation:

- [Window Functions Tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)
- [Window Function Calls](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)
- [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)